# C# AsyncEnumerable running/awaiting multiple tasks never finishes

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

I want to have a function which receives a `Task<bool>` and running it in X tasks.

For that I've wrote the below code:

```
public static class RetryComponent
{
    public static async Task RunTasks(Func<Task<bool>> action, int tasks, int retries, string method)
    {
        // Running everything
        var tasksPool = Enumerable.Range(0, tasks).Select(i => DoWithRetries(action, retries, method)).ToArray();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasksPool);
    }

    private static async Task<bool> DoWithRetries(Func<Task<bool>> action, int retryCount, string method)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (retryCount <= 0)
                return false;

            try
            {
                bool res = await action();
                if (res)
                    return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Log it
            }

            retryCount--;
            await Task.Delay(200); // retry in 200
        }
    }
}
```

And the following execution code:

```
BlockingCollection<int> ints = new BlockingCollection<int>();
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100000))
{
    ints.Add(i);
}
ints.CompleteAdding();

int taskId = 0;
var enumerable = new AsyncEnumerable<int>(async yield =>
{
    await RetryComponent.RunTasks(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            int myTaskId = Interlocked.Increment(ref taskId);

            // usually there are async/await operations inside the while loop, this is just an example

            while (!ints.IsCompleted)
            {
                int number = ints.Take();

                Console.WriteLine($"Task {myTaskId}: {number}");
                await yield.ReturnAsync(number);
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }, 10, 1, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
});

await enumerable.ForEachAsync(number =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
});
```

where `AsyncEnumerable` is from `System.Collections.Async`.

The console shows Task 10: X (where x is a number in the list..).

When I remove the `AsyncEnumerable` everything works as intended (all tasks are printing and the execution ends)..
For some reason, which I cannot find for a lot of time, using `AsyncEnumerable` just ruins everything (In my main code, I need it to use `AsyncEnumerable`.. scalability stuff..) meaning that code never stops and only the last task (10) is printing. when i added more logs, i see that tasks 1-9 never finish.

So just to clear things up, I want to have multiple tasks doing async operations  and yield the results to a single AsyncEnumerable object which acts as a pipe. (this was the idea..)

Comment: How does it ruin everything?

Comment: because when its not in AsyncEnumerable, things work as intended and all the tasks are printing (instead of just task 10.)
Plus, this task wont end because tasks 1-9 never finish for a reason i dont know

Comment: So with `AsyncEnumerable` being used, it only prints `Task 10: {number}` ? Please remember that when phrasing questions, only you understand the context behind that, it's best to describe the problem and the expected/intended solution to help us understand.

Comment: i think i made it more clear now.

Comment: [First you know that Tasks != Parallel?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/)

Comment: @Selvin yeah, i wrote parallel by mistake, i didnt mean that

Comment: Still not really understanding what the expected outcome is, should it go to `Task 11` and `Task 12`? You specify 10 tasks to run but your `BlockingCollection` has 100,000 items inside which your code is processing entirely, the last task picks up all other items retrieved from `ints`. Can you provide examples of what it looks like with a non async enumerable and what the desired behavior is?

Comment: All 10 tasks should display numbers. This is a pretty streight forward from the code.. a task just takes a number a print it. The problem is when i use AsyncEnumerable, tasks 1-9 just dont display something.. Its like they are dumped . also the execution wont stop like the tasks are still running but dont do anything

Comment: So I've run the code locally, tasks 1-9 are at the very top of the command window.

Comment: Good. So why only task 10 is printing results? Cause when you dont use the AsyncEnumerable, they will also print results

Comment: I apologize, I commented on this during my lunch hour today. Having had a look, I'm still baffled as to what exactly it is you're trying to achieve with the various bits of logic. What I can see from running this locally is your first 9 tasks are blocked, and 10 picks up the rest. Are you trying to create a pub-sub queue?

Comment: @ColinM imagine the asyncEnumerable as a pipe and the tasks inside as producers. they produce and send the data they make through the pipe.
The problem is, if you run the program, that only the last task is working and the other aren't finishing.
if you comment the "var enumerable = ..." wrapping, you'll see that all tasks are working as intended and the program finish executing. with the wrapping on the asyncEnumerable (the pipe) only the last task is working and the others never finish

Comment: I am unfamiliar with `AsyncEnumerable`, thank you for describing its execution context. What I found with this code was that when I instead used a `foreach` on `ints` without using `Take` that it was able to iterate through the tasks correctly, which is what led me to believe that the use of `BlockingCollection` and `Take` is blocking/locking your first tasks while they wait for the queue to become available again. The code also never gets past the `ForEachAsync` block.

Comment: @ColinM how? i changed it to take an item from a list (instead of blockingCollection) and same results.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cJ6rLW7A - I've moved the `Console.WriteLine` call to after the `yield.ReturnAsync` so it only prints the `Task {taskId}: {number}` when the job is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the enumerator/generator pattern is sequential, but you're trying to do a multi-producer, single consumer pattern. Since you use nested anonymous functions, and stack overflow doesn't show line numbers, it's hard to describe exactly which part of the code I'm referring to, but I'll try anyway.

The way that AsyncEnumerable works is basically to wait for the producer to produce a value, then wait for the consumer to use the value, then repeat. It does not support the producer and consumer running at different speeds, hence why I say this pattern is sequential. It does not have a queue of produced items, [only the current value](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable/blob/b4ab246cf32655470c57b80fb687ce543054c44b/src/AsyncEnumerator.cs#L194). [ReturnAsync does not wait](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable/blob/b4ab246cf32655470c57b80fb687ce543054c44b/src/AsyncEnumerator.cs#L215-L222) for the consumer to use the value, instead you are supposed to await the task that it returns, which gives you a signal that it's ready. Therefore we can conclude that it's not thread-safe.

However, `RetryComponent.RunTasks` runs 10 tasks in parallel and that code calls `yield.ReturnAsync` without checking if anyone else has already called it and if so if that task is complete. Since the Yield class only stores the current value, your 10 concurrent tasks overwrite the current value without waiting for the `Yield` object to be ready for a new value, so 9 of the tasks are lost and are never awaited. Since those 9 tasks are never awaited, the methods never complete and `Task.WhenAll` never returns, and neither do any of the other methods in the entire call stack.

[I created an issue on github](https://github.com/Dasync/AsyncEnumerable/issues/32) proposing they improve their library to throw exceptions when this happens. If they implement it, your catch block would write the message to the console and rethrow the error, putting the task in a faulted state, which would allow `task.WhenAll` to complete and therefore your program wouldn't have hung.

You could use multi-threaded synchronization APIs to ensure only one task at a time calls `yield.ReturnAsync` and await the return task. Or you could avoid using a multi-producer pattern as a single producer can be an enumerator easily. Otherwise you'll need to completely rethink how you want to implement the multi-producer pattern. I suggest [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) which is built-in to .NET Core and available in the .NET Framework as a NuGet package.

Comment: i freaking knew something was bad with this.. i checked my code more times than i can count..

Answer (score 3):

@zivkan is absolutely right about the sequential producer pattern. If you want to have concurrent producers that for a single stream, it is still possible to implement with the AsyncEnumerable library, but requires some extra code.

Here is an example of a solution for the problem with concurrent producers and consumers (only one consumer in this case):

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var e = new AsyncEnumerable<int>(async yield =>
            {
                var threadCount = 10;
                var maxItemsOnQueue = 20;

                var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
                var consumerLimiter = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 0, maxCount: maxItemsOnQueue + 1);
                var produceLimiter = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: maxItemsOnQueue, maxCount: maxItemsOnQueue);

                // Kick off producers
                var producerTasks = Enumerable.Range(0, threadCount)
                    .Select(index => Task.Run(() => ProduceAsync(queue, produceLimiter, consumerLimiter)));

                // When production ends, send a termination signal to the consumer.
                var endOfProductionTask = Task.WhenAll(producerTasks).ContinueWith(_ => consumerLimiter.Release());

                // The consumer loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    // Wait for an item to be produced, or a signal for the end of production.
                    await consumerLimiter.WaitAsync();

                    // Get a produced item.
                    if (queue.TryDequeue(out var item))
                    {
                        // Tell producers that they can keep producing.
                        produceLimiter.Release();
                        // Yield a produced item.
                        await yield.ReturnAsync(item);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // If the queue is empty, the production is over.
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });

            e.ForEachAsync((item, index) => Console.WriteLine($"{index + 1}: {item}")).Wait();
        }

        static async Task ProduceAsync(ConcurrentQueue<int> queue, SemaphoreSlim produceLimiter, SemaphoreSlim consumerLimiter)
        {
            var rnd = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10);
                var value = rnd.Next();

                await produceLimiter.WaitAsync(); // Wait for the next production slot
                queue.Enqueue(value); // Produce item on the queue
                consumerLimiter.Release(); // Notify the consumer
            }
        }
```

Comment: Odd that the ProduceAsync is passed consumerLimiter and produceLimiter, Aka when i read all this it sounds like, you have a bunch of tasks, not sure why your wrapping them in Task.Runs, anyway, then each one of these has work, but somehow you want to relate them to other work, outer work, why? its almost like you have tasks which have tasks/work, which you want to throttle but inside the current task. I think ur problems mostly come from passing consumerLimiter and produceLimiter. Interesting tho wsh i knew what you were trying to do. oh i see this isnt the man question